# Create an RMarkdown BeamerPoster template

Tags: r-markdown, beamer, a0poster

I would like to create a BeamerPoster https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter (or some other a0poster-like poster format) using Rmarkdown.  This seems possible reading http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html. Before I start from scratch,  I thought I would ask to see if anyone has done this and would share or point me to a template so I do not have to recreate the wheel.  Specifically, I would like to modify the BeamerPoster found at https://github.com/STAT-ATA-ASU/STT3851ClassRepo/blob/gh-pages/Poster/PosterTemplate2.Rnw
into an Rmarkdown template for creating a poster.  The good folks at RStudio have created very nice RMarkdown templates for slides, vignettes, documents, etc.  A poster format for RMarkdown would be a fantastic addition ;)

Comment: Not that I know of...

Comment: you can find a poster template here: https://github.com/exporl/kuleuven-templates

Comment: Is it example still working? When I try to 'knit' poster-R-example.Rmd, I receive following error message: 

(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 369.88582pt x 132.0746pt.)
Runaway argument?
\par \begin {columns} \par \column {(\linewidth -1cm)*\real {0.500000\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> poster-r-example.tex
                        
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that this is not the direct answer to your question, especially *whether there is a Rmarkdown template for `BeamerPoster`*. However, I'm sure that **there is a poster format for RMarkdown**. Although they are HTML based, they would deserve to be tried:

1. [Brent Thorne](https://github.com/brentthorne)'s [`posterdown`](https://github.com/brentthorne/posterdown)
2. [rstudio/pagedown](https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown) by Yihui Xie and Romain Lesur